# Exercise: every group embeds into a group with trivial center

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Here is my attempt to show that [every group embeds into a group with a trivial center, which is given as an exercise here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4348195).

I tried doing the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work™ and picked an opaque, propertyless element $k$ and tried to staple it onto $G$.

In order to make the argument easier to state, I looked at formal products that alternate between elements of $G$ and powers of $k$ and end in $k^0$ ... although it may not be necessary to interleave terms taken from $G$ and $k^\mathbb{Z}$ like this.

---

First, the [definition of an embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Universal_algebra_and_model_theory). $\varphi : G \to H$ is an embedding if and only if:

- $\varphi$ is injective.
- $\varphi(f(g_1, \cdots, g_n))$ is equal to $f(\varphi(g_1), \cdots, \varphi(g_n))$.
- $\langle g_1, \cdots, g_n \rangle \in R^G$ if and only if $\langle \varphi(g_1), \cdots, \varphi(g_n) \rangle \in R^H$ for all relation symbols $R$.

The theory of groups doesn't have any relation symbols, therefore we're just after an injective homomorphism. We need to preserve $e_G$, the identity which is a constant symbol, $\cdot_G$, the group operation, and ${\square}^{-1}_G$, inverses.

Suppose we have a group $G$ with center $Z(G)$.

(Thanks markvs for pointing out that the trivial group, when applied to the original construction, produces a new group with a nontrivial center).

If $G$ has a trivial center, then $G$ embeds into itself.

We now consider the remaining cases where $G$ has a nontrivial center.

I am now going to attempt to construct something I'm calling $G[k]$ (it might have a real name) which has a nontrivial center by construction.

Let $k$ be a propertyless group element in $G[k]$.

We now consider finite formal products of the form $g_1k^{a_1}g_2k^{a_2} \cdots g_{n-1}k^{a_{n-1}}g_n $.

Let's express these formal products as $\prod_{i \in n}g_i k^{a_{i}}$ **with the understanding that $a_n$ is constrained to be 0 in somewhat artifically so our formal product ends in $k^0$ which is equal to the identity element**.

I multiply these formal products by concatenating them.

I take inverses by swapping elements and inverting them (except for the final artificial $k^0$).

$$(g_1k^{a_1}g_2k^{a_2} \cdots g_{n-1}k^{a_{n-1}}g_{n}k^0)^{-1} = g^{-1}_nk^{-a^{n-1}} g^{-1}_{n-1} \cdots k^{-a_2} g^{-1}_2 k^{-a_1} g^{-1}_1 k^0 $$

Something is an identity element if and only if it is empty, a nonempty finite formal product of identity elements, or normalizes to an identity element in finitely many steps. Normalization occurs in the obvious way by removing interior identity elements and combining elements of $g$ with each other according to the group operation, or combining pairs of elements of the form $(k^a, k^b)$ into $k^{a+b}$.

$a$ and $b$ are equivalent if and only if $ab^{-1}$ is an identity element.

Modding the formal products out by this equivalence relation gives us back a group $G[k]$, I think.

$G$ has a trivial embedding into $G[k]$.

The intuition here is that $k$ does not satisfy any rules that it does not have to, therefore it will expel everything from the center of $G$ except for $e_G$. Powers of $k$ don't work either as prospective elements of the center because they don't commute with non-identity elements of $G$.

Comment: Hint: Cayley's theorem. If the group is too small, just put *that* into a larger similar group.

Comment: The process you attempted is called a "free product" (in this case with the infinite cyclic group). It also works, but takes a lot more effort.The usual notation is $G*\langle k\rangle$.

Comment: Oh, right, I can just grab a permutation of $G$-the-set not-corresponding to an element of $G$. I think I need to be a little bit careful how I pick it though. Thanks, @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Just use Cayley's theorem. It embeds $G$ into a symmetric group, and as long as $G$ has more than 2 elements, that symmetric group is centerless. If $G$ has 1 or 2 elements, just stick it into $S_3$.

Comment: Interestingly, your embedding does not work for the trivial group: it embeds the  trivial group into $\Bbb Z$ which has non-trivial center.

Comment: You might be interested to know that the following stronger result holds: every finite group is isomorphic with a subnormal subgroup of some finite complete group. (A group is complete if it has trivial centre and no outer automorphisms.)